# Different DateTimePicker issue

Tags: javascript, android

In this program I wish to display time on button. But it generates NullpointerException. I have tried with Log. It displays in log. However, It displays immediately error while starts displaying on the button. Please, could anyone show me what is the mistake in this program.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button android:id="@+id/button_date"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/button_time"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    //Declaration for class
    Views views;
    // Declartion for member vairables
    int hours;
    int minutes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       Views views = new Views();

        // pick up the default date using Calender class
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());

        hours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        setupTime(hours, minutes);
    }

    private  void setupTime(int hours, int minutes){
      //   Log.i("TAG", "------------ " + hours + " ");
      //  Log.i("TAG", "------------ " + minutes + " ");
        views.button_time.setText(String.valueOf(hours));

    }
    class Views{
        Button button_date;
        Button button_time;

        public Views(){
            Button button_date = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_date);
            Button button_time = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_time);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your are declaring button_date and button_time twice,try removing the one's inside the constructor

Answer (score 0):

In the Views class constructor you assign the views to other variables, not the ones declared in the class.

**Try this:**

```
public Views(){

        button_date = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_date);
        button_time = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_time);
}
```

**Explanation**

You are declaring 2 variables here:

```
class Views{
    Button button_date;
    Button button_time;
```

button_date and button_time, these variables will be around as long as the Views object is alive

Then, in your constructor, you are declaring them once again:

```
 public Views(){
        Button button_date = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_date);
        Button button_time = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_time);
    }
```

Even though, they have the same name, they are different variables that the ones declared before. These two variables will live only inside the constructor, and their value will not persist after the constructor has done its job.

Now, try to guess what values you have in the variables declared first ? If you guessed null, that is correct. And what happens when you try to call?

```
views.button_time.setText(...)
```

You call setText on a null variable, therefore NullPointerException occurs.

**Update 2**

The same issues is present here also:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Views views = new Views();
```

Change to this:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    views = new Views();
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. sorry friend I could not understand what does it mean. Please, could you explain me clearly.

Comment: Friend I found same result

Comment: Friend same result. No changes in the result

Comment: I've added some explanations for you, my friend

Comment: Well, guess why it's not working? It is the same mistake here: Views views = new Views(); should be views = new Views();

Comment: I have done what you have mentioned me earlier like this way

Comment: class Views{
    
     Button button_time;

        public Views(){
           
            button_time = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_time);
        }
    }

Comment: But it is giving me same result

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public Views() {
    this.button_date = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_date);
    this.button_time = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_time);
}
```

Comment: Friend same result. No changes

Comment: you might have to pass instance of mainActivity like

    Views views = new Views(this);

    public Views(MainActivity mainActivity){

            this.button_date = (Button) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.button_date);

            this.button_time = (Button) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.button_time);
       }...... Plz confirm with syntax of (Button) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.button_time);

Comment: Thank you friend. I appreciate your help. It is working now.

Comment: Check this out...   https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-listview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html  you have to pass MainActivity to inner class because it has the actual layout..

Comment: How? what was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Let's change this class - this part of code

```
class Views{
    Button button_date;
    Button button_time;

    public Views(){
        Button button_date = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_date);
        Button button_time = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_time);
    }
}
```

into

```
class Views{
    Button button_date;
    Button button_time;

    public Views(){
        button_date = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_date);
        button_time = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_time);
    }
}
```

Comment: Friend no change in the result.

Comment: Hi friend I have added day month and year. It is working but it is giving me in yy/mm/dd format. Please, could you show me how I can use dd/mm/yy format

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
//Declaration for class
Views views;
// Declartion for member vairables
int hours;
int minutes;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    views = new Views(this);

    // pick up the default date using Calender class
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());

    hours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    setupTime(hours, minutes);
}

    private  void setupTime(int hours, int minutes){
  //   Log.i("TAG", "------------ " + hours + " ");
  //  Log.i("TAG", "------------ " + minutes + " ");
    views.button_time.setText(String.valueOf(hours));

}

class Views{
    Button button_date;
    Button button_time;

    public Views(Activity activity){
        button_date = (Button)     activity.findViewById(R.id.button_date);
        button_time = (Button)     activity.findViewById(R.id.button_time);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Hi friend I have added the date but date is in yy/mm/dd. I want date in dd/mm/yy format. Please, could you help me. Following is my program          private void setupDate(int day, int month, int year) {
        views.button_date.setText(String.valueOf(day) + "/" +
                                      String.valueOf( month+1) + "/" +
                                       String.valueOf(year));

    }

Comment: private void setupDate(int year, int month, int day) { views.button_date.setText(String.valueOf(day) + "/" + String.valueOf( month+1) + "/" + String.valueOf(year)); }

Comment: try the code above, I could answer more correctly if you also give the function call code, the code must be like this

setupDate(day, month, year);